# CUBA : attributes for many-to-many association

Tags: cuba-platform

Is there a standard way in CUBA to modelize attributes for many-to-many association ? Documentation omits the topic so I guess it is not. In this case, is this in the roadmap ?

Comment: Since we are at SO here, can you explain what you already tried, what did not work and where were the problems?

Comment: In my opinion, a relation does not imply attributes. If you need attributes, create a linking entity (what you have probably already done).

Comment: linking entity is a solution indeed, I implemented another one, see answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For many-to-many association (e.g between Products and Providers), CUBA Studio generates automatically a link table (holding Provider ID and Product ID).

In order to handle specific attributes to this association (e.g Boolean preferredProvider) it would need to add the preferredProvider column in the link table and create a class holding the two IDs and the attribute.

It would also probably impact the platfom mechanism of fetching many-to-many associations.

I'm reasonably sure that CUBA Studio does not manage it as of 2.2.3 - no option in Studio GUI, nothing in doc. It is still of course possible to code the case manually but one would need to manually write JPQL. Not necessarily a big deal but losing a strong feature of the platform here just for one field.

So I created the preferredProvider field as a one-to-one association from Product to Provider, which is a valid workaround at the cost of an additional association.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13364237)

Comment: answered my own question through an edit of the said question, transfered answer to actual answer for the sake of clarity

Comment: Ah, got it now. In that case, you should finish it off by Accepting the answer to show everybody what the working solution was.